# How can avoid an error inline PowerShell script The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process?

Tags: windows, powershell, azure-devops

```
$signalsciencesAgent= Get-Item -Path "C:\Users\Shamim Reza\Desktop\zipfolderpath\sigsci-agent_latest.msi"
if (!(Test-Path $signalsciencesAgent.FullName)) {
    throw "File '{0}' does not exist" -f $signalsciencesAgent.FullName
}
 
try {
    $windowsInstaller = New-Object -com WindowsInstaller.Installer
    $database = $windowsInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember(
        "OpenDatabase", "InvokeMethod", $Null,
        $windowsInstaller, @($signalsciencesAgent.FullName, 0) 
    )
 
    $q = "SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property = 'ProductVersion'"
    $View = $database.GetType().InvokeMember(
        "OpenView", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $database, ($q)
    )
 
    $View.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null) 
    $record = $View.GetType().InvokeMember( "Fetch", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null ) 
    $signalsciencesagentversion = $record.GetType().InvokeMember( "StringData", "GetProperty", $Null, $record, 1 )


} catch {
    throw "Failed to get MSI file version: {0}." -f $_
}

Finally
{

Remove-Item $signalsciencesAgent

}
```

> **Above script I use for view .msi file version it's working well but when I use another command like Remove-Item or Invoke-RestMethod Then getting this error how can I handle this error**

```
    Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\Users\Shamim Reza\Desktop\zipfolderpath\sigsci-agent_latest.msi: The process cannot access 
    the file 'C:\Users\Shamim Reza\Desktop\zipfolderpath\sigsci-agent_latest.msi' because it is being used by another process.
    At line:30 char:1
    + Remove-Item $signalsciencesAgent
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\Shamim...gent_latest.msi:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Comment: Hard guess but, try releasing the ComObject before `Remove-Item` ?

Comment: @Santiago Squarzon
 
**Tried below command but got the same error please help me**

 `  [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($windowsInstaller) `

Answer (score 0):

It's becaeu the file is locked. Menaing still has a file handle to it. You need to release the lock.

This is not uncommon, PS notwithstanding, and there are lots of articles on the topic right here on Stackoverflow (use the search box to find them), as well as all over the internet. Use your favorite search engine to find them.

[PowerShell 'because it is being used by another process'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=PowerShell%20%27because%20it%20is%20being%20used%20by%20another%20process%27&va=b&t=hr&ia=web)

For Example:

[Because it is being used by another process: Why There Isn't a No-Dependency, One Line Powershell Solution](https://www.nikouusitalo.com/blog/because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process-why-there-isnt-a-no-dependency-one-line-powershell-solution)

```
$MethodDefinition = @'
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool CopyFile(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName, bool bFailIfExists);
'@

$Kernel32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MethodDefinition -Name 'Kernel32' -Namespace 'Win32' -PassThru

# You may now call the CopyFile function

# Copy calc.exe to the user’s desktop

$Kernel32::CopyFile("$($Env:SystemRoot)\System32\calc.exe", "$($Env:USERPROFILE)\Desktop\calc.exe", $False)
```

[Move-item: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/1c200943-49f5-4195-ba3b-ef7ec2a61438/moveitem-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process)

```
Function Wait-FileUnlock{
    Param(
        [Parameter()]
        [IO.FileInfo]$File,
        [int]$SleepInterval=500
    )
    while(1){
        try{
           $fs=$file.Open('open','read', 'Read')
           $fs.Close()
            Write-Verbose "$file not open"
           return
           }
        catch{
           Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $SleepInterval
           Write-Verbose '-'
        }
    }
}
```

> ## If you do not close the stream you will have one big memory leak.

Here is a function I built, and call as needed to release stuff when I'm done with it. Of course, this is a complete clear/release of everything, so, you need to tweak it for your needs.

```
Function Clear-ResourceEnvironment
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]

    [Alias('cre')]

    Param
    (
        [switch]$AdminCredStore
    )


    # Clear only variables created / used during the session
    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Variable) -DifferenceObject $AutomaticVariables -Property Name -PassThru |
    Where -Property Name -ne 'AutomaticVariables' |
    Remove-Variable -Verbose -Force -Scope 'global' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Remove-Variable -Name AdminCredStore -Verbose -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    # Clear only modules loaded during the session
    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Module) -DifferenceObject $AutomaticVModules -Property Name -PassThru |
    Where -Property Name -ne 'AutomaticVModules' |
    Remove-Module -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    # Clear only Aliases loaded during the session
    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Alias) -DifferenceObject $AutomaticAliases -Property Name -PassThru |
    Where -Property Name -ne 'AutomaticAliases' |
    Remove-Alias -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue


    # Clear only functions loaded during the session
    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Command -CommandType Function) -DifferenceObject $AutomaticFunctions  -Property Name -PassThru |
    Where -Property Name -ne 'AutomaticFunctions' |
    Remove-Item -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    # Clear all PSSessions
    Get-PSSession | 
    Remove-PSSession -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    # Clear static credential store, if switch is used
    If ($AdminCredStore)
    {Remove-Item -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\AdminCredSet.xml" -Force}
    Else
    {
        Write-Warning -Message "
        `n`t`tYou decided not to delete the custom Admin credential store.
        This store is only valid for this host and and user $env:USERNAME"
    }

    Write-Warning -Message "
    `n`t`tRemoving the displayed session specific variable and module objects"

    # Clear instantiate reasource interop
    $null = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::
            ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$Shell)

    # instantiate .Net garbage collection
    [System.GC]::Collect()
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
}
```